# Should I regularly erase cookies?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, cookies

Cookies really do make for a better experience on the web but do they also create a vulnerability? How often should I clean them out and what benefits are gained by doing so?

Comment: Just to alert you to the potential negatives of clearing your cookies - it will erase any sessions that you currently had open, so you'll have to re-login to any services you were using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies by themselves do not create any vulnerability. The goal to delete cookies is merely to improve privacy by keeping websites from tracking your activity.

A common way to track users, for instance, is when you visit several websites which include contents from some defined third-party tracking service (this content may be advertisement for the end-user, media & formatting resources like images, videos or fonts, traffic analysis for the webmaster, etc.). Upon your first visit, the third-party service will create a new cookie in your browser, then you will send him the same cookie upon each subsequent website you visit, allowing the third-party service to track your activity over several websites during your navigation (the cookie itself being usually programmed to have a lifespan of several years).

Session cookies, i.e. the cookies stored on your computer after you successfully logged in some website, may also present a security threat since they can be compared as a key allowing you to access the website without authenticating again.

Keeping such cookies could potentially allow another person to act as you on a website (whether maliciously or by mistake). Automatically deleting them guaranty you that you do not keep such forgotten keys somewhere on your system, and that the next time you will access to the website you will have to authenticate yourself.

Different browsers offer different options to configure how cookies are handled. Usually these options are present in the browser's configuration screen below a *Privacy* section:

- **Refuse cookies**: As the option states, you will just not use cookies anymore. I recommend to reserve such option only to *very* specific use-cases as it will have important side-effects, one of them being that cookies are the recommended and good way to handle your session tokens so disabling them will either prevent you completely to log in to some websites or make them fall-back to potentially less secure systems.
- **Keep the cookies until you quit the browser**: It means that no cookies will be kept after you have closed your browser. It will prevent any possibility to track you using the cookies between two browsing sessions, and require you to authenticate again to the websites where you have an account.
- **Block third-party cookies**: This is purely an anti-tracking feature since only the website you are currently visiting will be allowed to store cookies in your browser, this action will be refused to any third-party services. Enabling such option will usually have no impact on your session cookies (personally I did not encounter any unwanted side-effect to enabling this option, even if this may vary depending on the exact way you use your browser).

Moreover, most if not all browsers currently propose a **private window feature**: all cookies stored by the websites browsed while using this feature will be deleted upon window closure. Moreover, even if you visited the website previously in "normal" mode and it stored some cookie in your browser, it will not be able to access them when you visit it back while using the private mode.

This is a particularly good way to ensure that you do not mess with other people's cookies when using their browser for some search or as a quick workaround when you need to visit some website but want to prevent it to store or access any cookie.

Additionally, some browser may propose plugins allowing to even fine-grain cookies usage. A good example is Firefox's [Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org//firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/). It's main use is to automatically delete the cookies a certain time after you closed the associated tab, but it can also delete all cookies after a period of inactivity of the browser (for instance when you come back from lunch, you will have to authenticate again to your websites), all these option being of course configurable.

Comment: I use the option " delete all after closing the browser" and most of browsers allow you to open exceptions so i'm never logged out of the websites I care

Comment: Indeed, it's good to mention that most browser offer exception lists to personalize the setting on a per-site basis. Then, concerning the "logged out issue", it's mainly a matter of preference. Personally I prefer to logout when leaving a website and login when coming back, avoiding to leave opened sessions behind me, and I prefer to avoid having to maintain exception lists.

Answer (score 0):

You must always clear your cookies. Except in one case.

A cookie is just a text file where some information in plaintext format is stored. But you can not get an answer if you do not know the type of cookies that exist:

1. **Transient Cookies** (called also *session cookies*, *non-persistent cookies* or *in-memory cookies*): they are stored in the RAM and they  are deleted from the computer as soon as the browser is shut down. ***So you do not need to delete such cookies***. If your computer is compromised, you will be impersonated as long as your browser is open after their creation. To be impersonated using this type of cookies, the most frequent scenario is that you have a spyware installed on your computer, otherwise a proper implementation of such cookies is always done using SSL (HTTPS).
2. **Persistent Cookies**: they  are stored on the computer’s hard drive and contain information on user preferences for a website. These preferences can be used for further browsing sessions and are retained as long as the user allows them. Unlike transient cookies, these cookies are permanently stored and are not deleted when a browser is shutdown. ***So you need to delete such cookies***.
3. **Flash Cookies**: they are small Flash files such as video clips or gifs stored on your computer and they contain the same data as normal cookies and they function in the same way. ***Flash cookies cannot be deleted by any mechanism from the browser level. They can only be deleted manually or by using some special add-ons.*** So, if a Flash cookie is retained on a computer’s hard disk, it will be used as a backup for the normal cookie and hence can be used to recall the preferences of a particular user to a website.

If you are concerned by privacy issues, you need to delete cookies o in order not to be tracked (privacy protection) since you can not always check the cookies text files manually to see if they are getting some information from you (watch your online activity) that you do not want to share.

However, **there is one case you should not delete the cookies**: we are on Summer, suppose you want to travel to an other country and take your laptop with you to check your Yahoo, Gamil ... emails: if you do not use the 2-authentication factor, or if you use it but you do not activate your phone roaming option, you must avoid deleting your cookings just before moving so that you will be able to log into your email services that would let you to connect into your accounts even after they detect you are not in your country, thanks to the several cookies that date back to your browsing activities when you were in your original country, you did not delete.